# Android Object Layers

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an app where people can place objects in a SurfaceView -- images etc and they can resize it and things like that. Now i have a use case where someone can place in a frame like image -- lets say its a square image with the center as transparent. Now they can set an image that can go inside this frame and will be restricted to the bounds of that frame only and from there they can resize it as they will. Anyone does an implementation like this? Note that this is different from when a frame is full screen, that is easy to do. See my sample below:

[image]

The green is the main background area of the SurfaceView, he added the maroon/red frame, now he sets the picture to go in the frame (this is all within the same surface). The main difference this time around is that when he resize/move the image here, it should be bounded by the red frame ( he wont see it overlap outside like in the picture below). Anyone have experience how to do this on Android.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`clipRect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29) method of the Canvas. You can supply it with a rectangle specifying your frame before you draw the image to be framed. Something like this should work:

First when moving the frame you need to have a corresponding [`Rect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html):

```
myRect.set(frameleft, frametop, frameright, framebottom);
```

And in your `onDraw()` you clip the picture with this rectangle:

```
canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.clipRect(pictureRect);
canvas.drawBitmap(/*your drawing parameters for the image*/);
canvas.restore(); //Restore to drawing the entire canvas
```